# Laravel redirect with data in vue

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vue-router

I'm trying to redirect my controller with data in laravel to a vue file which then displays the data. It's a SPA and I'm using vue router.

Here is my controller redirection:

```
 return redirect('/bedankt-voor-je-bericht')->with('mailstatus', 'Bedankt voor uw bericht!');
```

And here is my vue file:

```
<script>

export default {

    mounted() {
        axios.get('/bedankt-voor-je-bericht')
            .then((response) => {
                console.log(response);
            });
    }
}
</script>
```

The response data does not include the `mailstatus` variable at the moment. But how will i accomplish this? Any help would be appreciated.

**Update:**

What is I want to send a form how would we accomplish that? Here is my code for the form:

```
<form method="post" action="/api/contact/send">
                    <div class="flex flex-col mb-[15px]">
                        <label class="font-bold text-[20px] mb-[5px]" for="">Naam</label>
                        <input class="border border-[#888888] rounded-[10px] min-h-[35px] px-2" type="text" name="name">
                    </div>
                    <div class="flex flex-col mb-[15px]">
                        <label class="font-bold text-[20px] mb-[5px]" for="">Emailadres</label>
                        <input class="border border-[#888888] rounded-[10px] min-h-[35px] px-2" type="text" name="email">
                    </div>
                    <div class="flex flex-col mb-[15px]">
                        <label class="font-bold text-[20px] mb-[5px]" for="">Bericht</label>
                        <textarea name="body" class="border border-[#888888] rounded-[10px] p-2 min-h-[215px] resize-none"></textarea>
                    </div>

                    <div class="flex justify-end">
                        <button type="submit" class="border border-[#25d097] bg-white text-[#25d097] w-full box-border p-2 rounded-[8px] hover:bg-[#25d097] hover:text-[#ffffff]">Verstuur</button>
                    </div>
                </form>
```

Then i have my `routes/api` like this `Route::post('/contact/send', ContactController::class);` And in my controller I have this:

```
public function __invoke(Request $request)
    {
        if ($request->email && $request->name && $request->body) {
            $mail = (new Mailsettings)->setup();

            $mail->setFrom($request->email, $request->name);
            $mail->addAddress(env('MAIL_USERNAME'), 'Plugzy');
            $mail->addReplyTo($request->email, $request->name);

            $mail->isHTML(true);
            $mail->Subject = 'Nieuwe e-mail Plugzy';
            $mail->Body    = $request->body;

//            $mail->send();

            return response()->json(['mailstatus', 'Bedankt voor uw bericht!'], 200);
        }

        return response()->json(['mailstatus', 'Er ontbreekt iets!'], 200);
    }
```

If the action is pointed to the api then there is no redirection to the next page.

Comment: redirection won't work with your scenario, try return response()->json(['mailstatus', 'Bedankt voor uw bericht!'], 200);

Comment: Thank you for answering Hassan, but I actually require a redirect because the code runs from an api: `/api/contact/send`. @HassanMalik

Comment: We do not use redirects in API routes. API's have only one purpose and it's to return data.

Comment: Also you're using Vue-router and redirection should be handled through that.

Comment: Well redirection is handled through my vue-router and the api actually returns data. The 
 reason why I use an api to run the controller code is because I can't run the controller from my `router.js`  and because it's an SPA it won't work to define routes in the `routes/web.php` @HassanMalik

Comment: Anyways thanks for your answer. I'm returning the response within the controller and in my vue-router I'm returning the correct route then that route will fetch the data from the api. @HassanMalik

Comment: Let's say I want to send a form which sends an email from my vue page, but want to do the email sending in the Controller. How would you do that? I'll update my question with the related code. @HassanMalik

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone that might run into this problem I've found an answer for returning a response without any page reloads. There's a npm package called [v-form](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vform)
thanks to this package I've managed to make it work as following:

This is my vue file for submitting the form:

```
<form @submit.prevent="sendemail()" @keydown="form.onKeydown($event)">
                    <div class="flex flex-col mb-[15px]">
                        <label class="font-bold text-[20px] mb-[5px]" for="">Naam</label>
                        <input
                            v-model="form.name"
                            class="border border-[#888888] rounded-[10px] min-h-[35px] px-2"
                            type="text"
                            name="name">
                    </div>
                    <div class="flex flex-col mb-[15px]">
                        <label class="font-bold text-[20px] mb-[5px]" for="">Emailadres</label>
                        <input v-model="form.email"
                               class="border border-[#888888] rounded-[10px] min-h-[35px] px-2"
                               type="text"
                               name="email">
                    </div>
                    <div class="flex flex-col mb-[15px]">
                        <label class="font-bold text-[20px] mb-[5px]" for="">Bericht</label>
                        <textarea v-model="form.body"
                                  name="body"
                                  class="border border-[#888888] rounded-[10px] p-2 min-h-[215px] resize-none">
                        </textarea>
                    </div>

                    <div class="flex justify-end">
                        <button type="submit" class="border border-[#25d097] bg-white text-[#25d097] w-full box-border p-2 rounded-[8px] hover:bg-[#25d097] hover:text-[#ffffff]">Verstuur</button>
                    </div>
                </form>

<script>

import Form from 'vform'

export default {

    data() {
        return {
            form: new Form({
                name: '',
                email: '',
                body: ''
            })
        }
    },

    methods: {
        sendemail: async function () {
            const response = await this.form.post('/api/contact/send')

            console.log(response);
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

And then in my `api.php` I've got this api route defined: `Route::post('/contact/send', ContactController::class);`. Which will activate my controller which has the following inside:

`return response()->json(['mailstatus', 'Bedankt voor uw bericht!'], 200);`. So now in the vue file I'll get the correct response without a page reload.